# Django get abstract model value in template

Tags: python, django

I have abstract models and it displays when item created. How can i get this variable and display in my template?

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    _created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Toy(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

views.py

```
toys = Toy.objects.all()
```

index.html

```
  {% for k in toys %}
    {{k.created}}
  {% endfor %}
```

I tried this one but it doesn't work.

Comment: The name of your field is `_created` (with an underscore) yet you try to access it using `.created`. Either remove the underscore or use `k._created` instead.

Comment: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'x._created'

Comment: Why did you name it such then?

Comment: I did not this is not my code.Is there any other ways to get this variable without renaming it?

Comment: Well, you can add a function to the abstract base class that returns the field value, such as `def created(self): return self._created` and then simply use `x.created` in your template.

Comment: It works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but if you only need the `_created` field, create an empty list in your view, and then populate it with the field for each instance. Then, return the new list as a context variable.

For example,

```
created_values = []

for value in Toy.objects.all():
    created_values.append(value._created)
```

The above is not tested, but I believe it should work.